# Minio retrievies 'Access Denied' even at requests with valid tokens, why is Minio ignoring STS tokens?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, minio

I am developing a Java service against Minio and I want to grant access for service users to Minio resources using S3 APIs. Therefore, I've implemented an AssumeRole Grant on a specified prefix:

```
AssumeRoleRequest assumeRoleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
                .withRoleArn(endUserRoleArn)
                .withDurationSeconds(14400)
                .withRoleSessionName(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .withPolicy(policyService.getRestrictedPolicy(bucket, prefix, restrictionType));

AssumeRoleResult assumeRoleResult = securityTokenService.assumeRole(assumeRoleRequest);
```

On the client side, I'm receiving these credentials and trying to make a PUT Object which leads to 'Access Denied'.

```
public void putObject(Credentials loadingzoneCredentials, String objectKey, InputStream inputStream) {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
                loadingzoneCredentials.getAccessKey(),
                loadingzoneCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
                loadingzoneCredentials.getSessionToken());


        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                        loadingzoneCredentials.getUri(),
                        loadingzoneCredentials.getRegion()))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .build();

        ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        objectMetadata.setUserMetadata(Map.of("loadtest", "true"));
        PutObjectResult putObjectResult = s3client.putObject(loadingzoneCredentials.getBucket(), objectKey, inputStream, objectMetadata);
    }
```

[image: Token]

This is all running in Docker on my local machine, Endpoints, region etc. are configured properly.

Stacktrace

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 16568362241C22F0; S3 Extended Request ID: 8f0b871f-bf3b-4a50-b2b3-e3b4f5447ae3; Proxy: null)
, S3 Extended Request ID: 8f0b871f-bf3b-4a50-b2b3-e3b4f5447ae3
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1819)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1403)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5247)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5194)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.access$300(AmazonS3Client.java:415)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$PutObjectStrategy.invokeServiceCall(AmazonS3Client.java:6308)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1840)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1800)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1732)
```

Comment: I was getting the same issue when trying to read/write to a "Requester-Pays" bucket. Check if that's the case, since you'll need to add in the header the param `x-amz-request-payer:requester`

Comment: No it's not an requester pays bucket.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$MINIO_ACCESS_KEY"
export AWS_SECRET_KEY="$MINIO_SECRET_KEY"
```

works just fine without providing a custom credentials loader. Please make sure the credentials are the ones matching minIO configuration.